# Call to undefined method Main_data::candidate_pro()

Tags: codeigniter

Controller

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Test extends CI_Controller {
        function __construct() {
            parent :: __construct();
            $this->load->model('Main_data');
        }
        
        public function my_profile() {
            $data['user_id'] = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
            $ids = $data['user_id'][0]['user_id'];
            $data['user_project'] = $this->Main_data->user_pro($ids);
            $this->load->view('user/my-profile',$data);
        }
    }
```

Model: Main_data

```
<?php  
    class Main_data extends CI_Model  {  
        function __construct()  {   
            parent::__construct();  
        }
        public function user_pro($ids) {
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('user_project');
            $this->db->where('user_id',$ids);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $result = $query->result_array();
            return $result;
        }
    }
```

In this code, I have controller `Test` where I have load Model `Main_data` and function `my_profile`. Now, When I run my program it generates an error as mention below:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Main_data::user_pro()
```

I don't know where am I doing wrong? So, How can I fix this error?

Comment: Hi where is the candidate_pro method in model

Comment: Sorry, actually it user_pro @Dolar

Comment: Hi where is the user_detail function in model

Answer (score 0):

first thing 
 load your models with lower case even if you named them with upper case
`$this->load->model('main_data');`

For the controller create a global variable `public $data` right after you defined the class. you may call this variable within your class with `$this->name`(in this case `$this->data`).

Within your `construct()`, after you load your model, make a call like this:

```
$this->data = $this->my_model->function_i_want_to_call(parameters);
```

it will load your global `$data` with the information you want from you function in the model

and make a function like this for your controllers

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->view('location_of_view',$this->data);
}
```

i have tried out your code, and with these modification it worked as intended.
this is the style i use for code igniter, maybe you won't like it but give it a try if you want :).
i hope this helps! have a nice day!